# How to return command window to dialog after "git log"?

Tags: git

A repository was on `HEAD -> master` then I made `git log` and it listed the history of commits. How to return in dialog mode to input commands? Currently terminal looks like below and it doesn't allow to execute git commands.

```
commit 5127f0488d8236dc71ff9886f24972e511d6b149 (tag: step-1)
Author: user <user@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu May 18 15:15:22 2023 +0300

    step-1
~
~
(END)
```

Comment: `Q` key seems to close the shell

Comment: @mimak yes, it does

Comment: When in doubt press `h`

Comment: @Guildenstern In `vim` it doesn't help much. ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exit+log

Comment: by the way it doesn't work in Android Studio terminal